# Funcionalidade: Alguém está respondendo

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Olá, gostaria de fazer uma sugestão, pois quando fazemos uma pergunta, sempre ficamos na expectativa que alguém responda-a logo. Será que não seria interessante ter uma funcionalidade de "Alguém está respondendo" assim como tem nos comentários do Facebook, ou até mesmo quando alguém está digitando no Whatsapp? O que vocês acham?

Comment: Isso parece-me uma funcionalidade completamente desnecessária. Qual a real vantagem de saber se alguém está respondendo ou não? Não consigo pensar em uma sequer.

Comment: Imagine que você poste uma pergunta às 18h15, precisando de uma resposta/ajuda pra resolver algum problema, se souber que tem alguém respondendo você pode esperar pra ver se já consegue resolver na hora, senão deixa pro outro dia. O real problema que vejo nessa funcionalidade seria a desmotivação de responder, já que outra pessoa está respondendo, mas enfim, essas funcionalidade nunca vai existir, já que já tomou 4 votos contras e só 1 a favor...

Comment: Eu até achei a ideia legal, mas penso que isso vai causar expectativas que nas pessoas, ainda mais se no meio do caminho eu desistir de responder, quem leu "alguém esta respondendo" e nota que não aparece resposta nenhuma vai perguntar "ué, foi um bug?"... não que presumam que é bug, mas expectativa do meu ponto de vista pode ter efeitos meio estranhos, ainda mais de alguém que esta ansioso para obter uma resposta. É apenas uma opinião pessoal. PS: não dei downvote, nem upvote, porque não tenho muita certeza.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a minha ideia era que aparecesse assim como nos comentários do Facebook "Alguém está respondendo..." e se a pessoa desistisse (apagasse o texto da resposta, saisse da página sem postar ou ficar muito tempo sem digitar) esse "Alguém está respondendo..." sumiria e imagino que a impressão de quem leu tal frase é que a pessoa desistiu, assim como no Whats fica lá "Fulano está digitando" depois some e tu já sabe que o cara desistiu... Ainda penso que o maior problema é o citado pelo Maniero, que desestimularia outras pessoas de responder...

Comment: @KaduAmaral sim, eu entendo bem como funciona, uso redes sociais e aplicativos mensageiros, eu entendo a ideia toda, e acho a ideia boa no geral como disse, só quis dizer que coisas assim podem ter efeitos inesperados, principalmente sobre a expectativa de quem esta acinosamente procurando por ajuda.

Comment: Então, eu concordo contigo e tu comigo... rsrs não sei o que estamos discutindo então... kkk

Answer (score 5):

Eu acho ótimo, embora tenha alguns detalhes que precisam ser definidos para indicar o que é "alguém está respondendo". Não é fácil ter um critério que diga isto com clareza.

Alguém está digitando algo no campo de resposta? A pessoa pode só estar testando um *markdown*, ou outra coisa, ou vendo se responde, mas não sabe de fato.

A pessoa teria que clicar em algo para dizer que vai responder? Isto não indica que seja verdade, que irá concluir, que será rápido, que não será abusado, o que dará um falso positivo, ou que a pessoa esquecerá ou não saberá que tem que clicar, o que dará um falso negativo. Nem falei que piora a UX.

Uma coisa é informar que a pessoa vai dizer algo, outra que ela dará uma resposta.

Um ponto negativo é que pode desestimular outras pessoas responderem, e no fim ficar sem nada. Pior ainda se disser quem. Imagine aparecer "Jon Skeet is answering" :D

Nem pensei na questão da carga dos servidores.

Comment: Entendo o seu ponto, mas não vejo os falsos positivos como um problema, pois a pessoa pode desistir de responder então quando ela cancela a resposta ou simplesmente sai da página sem responder pode ser caracterizado como desistencia de resposta então a informação "Alguém está respondendo" simplesmente desapareceria. Acho que o ponto mais crucial seria o gasto com servidores para o recurso...

Comment: Sei que hoje já tem um recurso de "salvar rascunho", a exibição de "alguém está respondendo" talvez seria apenas a verificação se existe um rascunho muito recente...

Comment: Quantas vezes eu começo, largo lá, termino depois, ou só abandono, horas ou dias depois :D

Comment: @bigown achei uma resposta de 2015 com um aviso de que o autor iria complementar... Já se passaram 2 anos kkkk

Comment: @Articuno minha? Eu devo ter algumas assim :) Sabe qual?

Comment: Tem uma aqui @Articuno https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96464/66203

Comment: "Jon Skeet is answering" é um pedido para ficar quieto e esperar pela sabedoria